# Blackberry: How to set video resolution before recording

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I need to record video with specific resolution (as least as possible).

```
private void startRecording(Player player, net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager parentManager)
{
    try
    {
        if (player == null)
        {
            player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("capture://video?encoding=video/3gpp");
            player.addPlayerListener(this);
            player.realize();

            RecordControl recordControl = (RecordControl) player.getControl("RecordControl");
            VideoControl videoControl = (VideoControl) player.getControl("VideoControl");

            if (videoControl != null)
            {
                final Field videoField = (Field)videoControl.initDisplayMode( VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field" );

                try
                {
                    videoControl.setDisplaySize(1, 1);
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                videoControl.setVisible(true);
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        if(parentManager != null)
                        {
                            if(videoField.getIndex() == -1)
                            {
                                parentManager.insert(videoField, 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }   

        // here i get null
        CameraControl cameraControl = (CameraControl) player.getControl("CameraControl");
        int[] resolutions = cameraControl.getSupportedVideoResolutions();
        cameraControl.setVideoResolution(resolutions.length / 2 - 1);   

        recordControl.setRecordLocation("test.3gp");\
        recordControl.startRecord();    

        player.start();

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

but for some reason `(CameraControl) player.getControl("CameraControl");` return `null`

How can i specify resolution for recording video?

P.S. Blackberry OS 5.0, Torch 9800

**Update:**

In case when I using

```
capture://video?encoding=video/3gpp&mode=mms
```

or

```
capture://video?encoding=video/3gpp&width=240&height=180&video_codec=MPEG-4&audio_codec=AMR
```

I get `event=error` and `eventData=2` in `PlayerListener.playerUpdate(Player player, String event, Object eventData)` method

Description for `eventData=2` I found [here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/javax/microedition/media/PlayerListener.html#ERROR):

> Invalid parameter: a parameter was specified with an invalid value.

Can someone explain me why my params incorrect?

Comment: Regarding the null object, [take a look at Mister Smith's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9666104/119114), which also points to [this BlackBerry document](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Advanced-Multimedia-Supplement-API-What-s-Supported/ta-p/770659), which says that they did not implement `setVideoResolution()`, as you unfortunately found out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This below link may helps you:

[Video Recording in Blackberry](http://alishaik001.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/blackberry-video-recording-in-blackberry/)

Answer (score 2):

The user is able to modify the recording settings - on higher end phones there are three different quality levels, but the recorder defaults to the highest quality. I've tried to set it to the medium quality level - 640x480, but haven't been able to find a way to do that.

Since you are asking for the lowest quality, you might have some luck. You can specify "MMS" quality, and the video recording will be very low quality, which is what you want.

I referenced "[RIM blackberry Record 3GP video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666057/rim-blackberry-record-3gp-video)" which says that adding `&mode=mms` to the player string will give you MMS quality.  Unfortunately, it also appears to limit the duration to 30 seconds.

Comment: you have *exactly* 9000 reputation :O

Comment: I tried `&mode=mms` but this not help me. I updated question with more details